# TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: array, typescript, reactjs, express, promesas

estoy intentando guardar en el estado de un componente en React una lista de usuarios que obtengo de una consulta a la base de datos mediante una api en express, estoy obteniendo bien los datos, pero a la hora de insertarlos en el estado me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
```

En algunos  sitios que he buscado dicen que este problema se presenta cuando intentamos trabajar con tipos de datos diferentes, pero la consulta a la base de datos devuelve un array y en el lugar que quiero ponerlo en el estado tiene ese mismo formato, entonces no tengo la menor idea de que pueda estar pasando, nunca he tropezado con este error ya que no tengo mucha experiencia. Adjunto debajo el código de mi componente. Saludos y gracias de antemano.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { getAll } from '../FetchServer';

import { List, Avatar, Button, Skeleton } from 'antd';

class Users extends Component {
 state = {
  initLoading: true,
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  list: []
 };

 //Aquí obtengo los datos
 fakeDataUrl = async () => {
  const aux = await getAll();
  return aux.data;
 };

 //Aquí intento poner los datos en el estado, pero en vez de lograrlo, me devuelve el error antes mencionado.
 componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.fakeDataUrl());
  this.setState({
   initLoading: false,
   data: this.fakeDataUrl(),
   list: this.fakeDataUrl()
  });
 }

 componentWillMount() {
  console.log(this.state.list);
 }

 render() {
  const { initLoading, loading, list } = this.state;
  const loadMore =
   !initLoading && !loading ? (
    <div
     style={{
      textAlign: 'center',
      marginTop: 12,
      height: 32,
      lineHeight: '32px'
     }}
    >
     <Button onClick={this.onLoadMore}>loading more</Button>
    </div>
   ) : null;

  return (
   <List
    className="demo-loadmore-list"
    loading={initLoading}
    itemLayout="horizontal"
    loadMore={loadMore}
    dataSource={list}
    renderItem={(item) => (
     <List.Item actions={[ <a>edit</a>, <a>more</a> ]}>
      <Skeleton avatar title={false} loading={item.loading} active>
       <List.Item.Meta
        avatar={
         <Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />
        }
        title={<a href="https://ant.design">{item.name.nickname}</a>}
        description="Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team"
       />
       <div>content</div>
      </Skeleton>
     </List.Item>
    )}
   />
  );
 }
}

export default Users;
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer tu `componentDidMount` asincróno, es decir: `async componentDidMount` y en el `setState` corregir y cambiar la linea del list por esto: `list: await this.fakeDataUrl()`

Comment: Muchas gracias una vez más German, después de agregar al código lo de tu comentario solucioné mi error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para complementar el comentario que te hice, te explicaré un poco qué es lo que te estaba sucediendo.

El error `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance` normalmente tiende a aparecer cuando se intenta recorrer o iterar (hacer un `for` un loop `while`) sobre un objeto que no tiene características para ser iterable. [Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Iteration_protocols) un ejemplo de como funcionan los iteradores en Javascript.

Ahora, por otro lado, tienes tu método `fakeDataUrl` que lo estás definiendo como un método asíncrono `async`, de esta forma, entonces lo que devuelve un llamado a esa función no es el objeto que retornas, si no una promesa.

Entendiendo esto, entonces es fácil identificar que cuando ejecutas esta línea:

```
this.setState({
  initLoading: false,
  data: this.fakeDataUrl(),
  list: this.fakeDataUrl()
});
```

El valor que está tomando la key `data` y la key `list` son promesas, y las promesas, no cumplen las condiciones para ser iterables (debido a la forma como está definida la clase internamente, lee el link que te dejé arriba). Así que para que tome el resultado que definiste en el `return` del método, necesitas decirle a tu función asíncrona que esperaremos a que dé un resultado, y para ello debemos agregarle un `await` a la función, quedando así el código:

```
this.setState({
  initLoading: false,
  data: await this.fakeDataUrl(),  // aquí
  list: await this.fakeDataUrl(),  // y aquí
});
```

Pero seguramente si haces ese solo cambio, el transpilador te arrojará un error ya que `await` es una palabra reservada, y al hacer esto estamos diciéndole al código que `componentDidMount` tiene que esperar algo, y Javascript por naturaleza no es asíncrono, entonces es necesario definir a `componentDidMount` como asíncrono, y para ello definimos: `async componentDidMount`.

De esta forma ya tu código funciona como esperas. Espero poder haberte ayudado con el comentario y la explicación, si sientes que algo no quedó claro, puedes comentarme y con gusto te ayudaré a resolver tus inquietudes